# Tracing through a java program

Tags: java, debugging

Is there a way to trace through a given program step by step? I am given a java program with 2 arrays and I am just looking for some program to trace through each line step by step to see what is going on in the program.

Comment: debug the code by using ide like eclipse, netbean, intellij etc.

Comment: Or, if OP is working from the command line, use the jdb command line debugger https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdb.html

Comment: Or, if you just want to do some quick and dirty debugging, System.out.println(<relevant variable>); is not a bad option either.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the start of your program, then run the program in debug mode. Are you using an IDE? or a text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "Debug" in Eclipse, and then use the step-over, step-through features.

Answer (score 1):

With Netbeans you could:
Press F7 to start debugging.  F8 you step over a line (in case its a method) while F7 you step into the methods.  F4 would run till cursor (also useful).
In the variables tab, you'll see the values and types of each variable.  You could also add you want to "watch".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what IDE do you use. But for first you can use:

1. breakpoints and step-by-step execution
2. debug messges, simple: `System.out.println`. You can also use:

   - Log4j
   - JDK logging
   - Use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`.
3. [Profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)#Use_of_profilers) - more powerfull tool